# How to give a .gif animation variable frame delay speeds in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, layers, animation, video, layer-composition

When exporting an animated gif in Gimp (each layer is a frame of the animation), you can set the speed between each frame (layer) as a fixed number, by default 100 milliseconds. How do you instead specify:

- 100 ms between layers 1 and 2
- 200 ms between layers 3 and 4
- 500 ms between layers 4 and 5

and so on? If not .gif, then how about .png animation?

[image]

Comment: If you are using windows, there is a really old free program called gif animator v1 that let you do this on a frame-by-frame basis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add a delay to a specific layer you put the duration at the end of the layer name: `Layer1 (200ms)`. This is the time this layer remains visible until it is covered by the next frame. The duration set there may be ignored/changed by browsers/players if too short or too log.

You can use the same principle to set how the layer is used:

- `(combine)` to add it over image displayed so far
- `(replace)` to replace the whole image.

So for instance, an image with the following layers:

[image]

Will show

- a blue square for 3 seconds,
- then a black square is added and is visible for 1 second over the blue square
- then a red square with a transparent center (through which you see the white of the GDSE page) replaces everything for 2 seconds

[image]

Comment: To create a fast flashing effect between two layers with uneven delay per frame, can this be done without duplicating each layer multiple times?

Comment: You can always replace consecutive copies of the same layer by a single layer displayed with a longer duration, if this is the question.

Comment: consecutive copies of a layer, but interspersed with multiple copies of another layer. think of a zipper

Comment: No, you have to create the frames where they occur. Bu if you do this for all your layers, you can use the [ofn-interleave-layers script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/). Use one of the "Single layer" option with "Merge: No", and name the layer with the delay before you give it to the script.